# How to use a UICollectionView inside a UIInputViewController for a custom keyboard extension?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

A UICollectionView would be ideal for presenting pages of image options to use in a UIInputViewController for a custom iOS keyboard.

Is it possible to use the UICollectionView inside a Keyboard Extension, or does the functionality need to be replicated manually?

Comment: On further investigation, I have found that you can, as long as you do it programmatically. I found these two tutorials to be very helpful in creating a UICollectionView programmatically... and it worked great inside a keyboard extension input view controller:

http://randexdev.com/2014/07/uicollectionview/  and 

http://randexdev.com/2014/08/uicollectionviewcell/

Comment: Any idea why they don't work with an XIB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a UICollectionView inside a UIInput ViewController for a Keyboard Extension.

The easiset way to do it is programmatically. The links I provided in my comment above will get you started.